# Facing Issue with Before advice in Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-annotations

My project is Spring and Hibernate based. I am familiar with Spring AOP.

There is a requirement that whenever any method of DAO layer is called(by service layer), I need to check some logic and based on that DAO layer method should be allowed to proceed. So, i was thinking of using AOP here. The **aspect** will have one method, with **before advice** applied to it, which will have some logic and will return true or false accordingly and based on the **boolean** value, returned from aspect, DAO method will be allowed to continue to do its persistence logic. For e.g. if **true** is returned, DAO persistence process will happen and if **false** is returned, persistence logic will not occur.

But, the challenge I am facing is how to return the **boolean** value from Aspect to DAO layer method.

Is it possible to return a value from the **advising method**(i.e. method written in Aspect) to the **target method** with **Before advice**? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If your DAOs could share an interface with a 'proceed/execute/doStuff' method then you could call it from the Advice(or not).

If not, why don't you add a flag to your DAOs and set it from the advice, then on the DAO check it before proceeding and set it back to the default state before leaving the method.